# Find $~c~$ such that $~{P(Z<c)=0.65}~$where $~Z\sim\mathcal N(0,1)~$ using interpolation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, interpolation

$$\begin{align}
Z&\sim \mathcal N(0,1)
\end{align}$$

$$ \text{Find the value of }~~  c ~~\text{such that}~~ P(Z<c)=0.65$$

$$ \Phi(x):=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_{\text{s} }(x) \mathrm dz $$

Following values are known from the table of normal distribution.

$$ \Phi(0.38)=0.6480~~,~~\Phi(0.39)=0.6517 $$

What I can't understand currently is the following equation.

$$\begin{align}
c&=0.38+{0.65-0.6480 \over 0.6517-0.6480 }(0.39-0.38)\\&=0.385
\end{align}$$

The book states that the interpolation was used here.

Can you tell me the logic which is used here, or some useful link for which describes of it?

BTW I independently got $0.385$ using a functional calculator with greedy way(this could be done since $~ \Phi(x) ~$ is an increasing function) but too stupid way it is.

**ADD**

$$\begin{align}
a&:=0.38\\
b&:=0.39\\
\Phi_a&:=\Phi(a)\\
\Phi_b&:=\Phi(b)\\
\Phi'_b&:=\Phi_b-0.0017 \\
c&=a+ {\Phi'_b -\Phi_a\over \Phi_b-\Phi_a }(b-a)
\end{align}$$

Comment: The basic idea is: for $x\in[0.38,0.39]$, which is a very small interval, we can approximate $\Phi$ by a linear segment connecting between $(0.38,\Phi(0.38))$ and $(0.39,\Phi(0.39))$, whose equation I’d like to denote as $f$. The book just finds $c$ such that $f(c)=0.65$. Strictly speaking, we don’t have $\Phi(c)=0.65$, we just have approximation, which will be enough for our usage in some circumstances.

Comment: Following your advice, I got 0.385 using the general formula $~y-y_1={y_2-y_1\over x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)~$. Thank you.